# R - Test hypothesis that parameter is equal to something

Tags: r

I am studying economics and we just started learning with R in RStudio and we got homework, I am really bad at this, I have almost all other tasks done but I have no idea b idea how to do this (sorry if it is pretty simple)
We got some data and we should estimate this regression function (instead u there should be e):
[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNs83.jpg)

So far I have this:

```
tabulka = read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, sep= "")

regrese2 = lm(log(Output)~log(LPrice)+log(KPrice)+log(FPrice), data=tabulka)

summary(regrese2)
```

Not sure if it is correct, if you see mistake please correct me :)

But what I really need help is that we have to test hypothesis if `β1 = 1` and also if `β2 = β3 = 0`. Could someone tell me do i do this? Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Please see this answer from CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211584/testing-linear-restriction-in-r

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `library(car)`

And use `linearHypothesis` function for Joint hypotheses.

Your code should look something like this:

```
linearHypothesis(regrese2, c(“LPrice = 0”))



linearHypothesis(regrese2, c(“KPrice = 0”,  “FPrice = 0”))
```

Answer (score 0):

The tests of beta_2 = 0 and beta_3 = 0 will be given by `summary(regrese2)` (note that those tests are conditional on the other terms in the model).

There are 3 ways (maybe more) of testing beta_1 = 1, which one you should use would be determined by the teacher:

1. Run the summary function `summary(regrese2)` and use the effect size and standard error from the summary for the first regression term and plug those numbers into the book formula and do the test "by hand".  This is often what the teacher expects students to do in more basic classes.
2. Subtract `log(LPrice)` from `log(Output)` then use that as the response variable and test to see if the coefficient on `log(LPrice)` is equal to 0.
3. Use the `offset` function: `log(LPrice) + offset(log(LPrice))` on the right side of the `~`, then again test the coefficient for `log(LPrice)` against 0.